# Connection limit for SQLDB with small_plan (Bluemix)

Tags: ibm-cloud

What is the concurrent connection limit for SQLDB Small plan? We have a liberty application bounded to a SQLDB service with Small plan and got the following error. DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-4712

Answer (score 2):

The Free Beta plan features 100MB per instance and 10 concurrent connections.

The Small plan features 10GB max per instance and 20 concurrent connections.

The Premium plan features 500GB max storage per instance and 100 concurrent connections.

See the link below for more information:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?ace_base=true/#/store/cloudOEPaneId=store&serviceOfferingGuid=0d5a104d-d700-4315-9b7c-8f84a9c85ae3&fromCatalog=true

If you think you're close to exhausting your connections, you should use the Monitoring and Analytics Service to monitor connection pools:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/monana/index.html#gettingstartedtemplate